# Get linkedin feed from 2 different companies

Tags: wordpress, linkedin-api

I'm developing a wordpress site for a company and i need to display the linkedin feed of that company and from a partner company. I've been using the Linkedin Company Updates plugin and it's really great, but i'm not sure it can do what i need. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take a look at this [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how to ask or answer questions and to learn more about how stackoverflow works.

Comment: how to use plugin
https://wordpress.org/plugins/company-updates-for-linkedin/#installation

Comment: thank you, but on the link you gave me they explain how to install and setup the plugin. i've managed to do that, i'm just not sure if i can fetch the feed from 2 companies on the same site, using only this plugin.